# Filtering values from kubectl output

Tags: json, kubernetes, jq, kubectl, jsonpath

I have a k8s cluster and get the list of images if I run:

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o jsonpath="{..image}" |\
tr -s '[[:space:]]' '\n' |\
sort |\
uniq -c
```

-this works.

Now, I have to list all images which do not start with a particular string, say "random.domain.com"

how to filter out attribute values using jsonpath?

I have tried out below.

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o jsonpath="{..image}[?(@.image!="random.domain.com")]" |\
tr -s '[[:space:]]' '\n' |\
sort |\
uniq -c
```

As a workaround, I am using -

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o jsonpath="{.items[*].spec.containers[*].image}" |\
tr -s '[[:space:]]' '\n' |sort |uniq -c| grep -v "random.domain.com"
```

But wanted to know how we can get this done by using jsonpath.

Thanks.

Comment: I think it cannot be done only using `jsonpath` because `kubectl` does not support Regular Expressions yet (see [#61406](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/61406) and [#72220](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/72220))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea how to work with jsonpath (atm). but here how you can do that with `jq`

```
kubectl get pods -o json | \ 
 jq '[.items[].spec.containers[].image | select(. | startswith("random.domain.com") | not )] | unique'
```

AFAIS, according to the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/jsonpath/), you can't do that with JSON path itself